# .Net Core 3.1 API Routing not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a fairly simple controller for my API.  One method returns all devices, and another method returns information on just one.  Both of them are HttpGet.

My route definition:

> ```
> [Route("api/device/list/{Id}")]
> [ApiController]
> public class DeviceController : ControllerBase
> ```

This method is always called when I pass in an ID:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<poiDevices> GetDeviceList()
```

The PostMan URL looks like this:

> https://localhost:5001/api/device/list/mycoolid

When the call above is made I want it to call this method below, defined as such with an Id parameter:

> ```
>     public ActionResult<DeviceDto> GetDeviceDetails(
>     [FromRoute] string Id)
> ```

The code above has a placeholder for an Id, so my expectation is for this method to be called, instead the generic method is called which returns all.  If I take the Id out of the URL the API returns 404 not found, meaning I messed up the routing piece of this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your controller like this.

```
[Route("api/device")]
[ApiController]
public class DeviceController : ControllerBase
{

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("list")]
  public ActionResult<poiDevices> GetDeviceList()  {

  }

  [Route("list/{id}")]
  public ActionResult<DeviceDto> GetDeviceDetails(
    [FromRoute] string Id)   {

  }

}
```

Comment: Damn it, I knew it was simple....decorate the method.....